# Email images not lining up out look 2007/10 vs everything else

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've checked out a few posts, and tried them. Didn't work. This may become a decision and tell clients this is what it is, but I don't want to come to that.

So after testing with Litmus, my main issue is the borders(left and right) vs the top and bottom image not lining up correctly on outbook 2007/10 vs everything else.

```
 <body>
 <style type="text/css">
body{
  color:#415b7c;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px; 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}

table {border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
  <td><!-- header -->
    <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td>
              <table width="600" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr><td>
                  <img src="http://wearehmc.com/emailTemp/VSAC/top.png" width="600" style="display:block">
                </td></tr>
              </table>
           </td>
        </tr>    
        <tr valign="top">
          <td>
            <table width="600" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#3d5b83; border-left-width:2px; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#3d5b83; border-right-width:2px; border-collapse: collapse; ">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    client log
                </td>
                <td>
                  <table cellpadding="10" style="color:#576276;">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <p style="font-weight:bold">
                          Text
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          text
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                   </table> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    client logo
                </td>  
             </tr>
            </table>

          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>
          <table width="600" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
                <td style="color:#ffffff; font-size:22px; font-weight:500; line-height:30px">
                  <table width="600" align="left" bgcolor="#659acf" cellpadding="20" style="border-left-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse; border-left-color:#3d5b83; border-left-width:2px; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#3d5b83; border-right-width:2px; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="color:#ffffff; font-size:24px; ">
                        text
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>      
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <table width="600" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr><td>
                  <img src="http://wearehmc.com/emailTemp/VSAC/bottom.png" width="600" style="display:block">
                </td></tr>
              </table>
           </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

  </td>
</tr></table>
```

I've taken out client copy and logos.

As I've said it may come down to a decision of not letting it line up in outlook 2007/10, while letting it work in others.

So if anyone has any suggestions, it would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For outlook (And gmail) You need to specify border="0" on your images.

```
<img src="/" width="" height="" alt="" border="0" style="display:block">
```

This should be on every image you use in your email, even spacers. (In fact, especially on spacers, since those will create unwanted empty space without any content)

Also, Outlook has trouble rendering cell-padding and spacing (2007 and 2010 both use microsoft WORD as their rendering engine, I'll let you imagine how great that is to render html-emails).

So you should really be using nested tables instead of cell-padding, with spacer images to create the inner spaces of your sections.

Oh, and I see that all your styling is not inline. This will cause problems with your html-email stability. (gmail will strip every styling that is not inline, as well as the #000000 color on links (use #000001 instead)).

Oh also. Border styles and colors. Those will not display properly everywhere. The solution is again nested tables. With bgcolor and 1 / 2px width spacers to give the illusion of borders.

Hope this all helps.  (I know this sounds like a lot of errors in your html-email, but once you get the hang of coding for the worst possible mail clients in mind, it'll become second nature! ;) )

Comment: With a minuet left in the work day, you have saved me. Also from what I've seen, valign becomes your friend.

Comment: Yep. Coding html-emails is a bit like going back to the 90s. It has it's own charm. :) Glad I could help!